# Calculation of velocity in onfling event

Tags: javascript, android, events, onfling

I want to reproduce onfling event in javascript.
I know I have to calculate px/time but I don't know what time I have to take for reference.

Comment: It might be good to include a link to the event you want to reproduce for reference and also share some code to show us what you have tried, then we can help more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

while this code is not fir for its intended purpose
it does demonstrate how to "to calculate px/time "

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Fling Me</title>
<style>
div{
   position:absolute;
   top:300px;
   left:300px;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
republicans must abandon trump or be complicit in his advocacy of assassinating a sitting president
<div></div>
<script>
'use strict';
(function(){
var mm,ox,oy,el,t,l,tt=0,tl=0,dt=0,dl=0,tmr,s;
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('mousedown',
   function(ev){
      el = ev.target;
      s = el.style ;
      ox=ev.offsetX; oy=ev.offsetY;
      t=ev.clientY;l=ev.clientX; 
      tmr = setInterval(function(){    
         dt = tt - t;
         dl = tl - l;
         tt = t;
         tl = l;            
      },30);
      el.addEventListener('mousemove',
         mm = function(ev){ 
            t=ev.clientY;l=ev.clientX;
            s.top =  t - ox + 'px';
            s.left = l - oy + 'px';            
         }
      );
      el.addEventListener('mouseup',
         function(ev){
            clearInterval(tmr);
            el.removeEventListener('mousemove',mm);
            tmr = setInterval(function(){
               s.top =  parseInt(s.top) - dt + 'px';
               s.left = parseInt(s.left) - dl + 'px';
            },30);
            setTimeout("location.assign(location.href)",2000);
         }
      );
   }
)})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi,i don't understand this part of code:  el.addEventListener('mouseup',
         function(ev){
            clearInterval(tmr);
            el.removeEventListener('mousemove',mm);
            tmr = setInterval(function(){
               s.top =  parseInt(s.top) - dt + 'px';
               s.left = parseInt(s.left) - dl + 'px';
            },30);
            setTimeout("location.assign(location.href)",2000);
         }
      );      Why do you set an other timer after mouse up?